# How can we set culture two character string in URL as optional route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, routes

I am working on MVC applicaiton. 
Required to set culture value to all the URL route..

I want as below. 
**Case 1:** www.abc.com (Default culture English ) if en then no need to showup on web URL.

**Case 2:** www.abc.com/fr

In my code I have added below code added but not working..
I want to set culture value from route only. no need to set hardcoded in each page Action Link..

How can I set by changing it.. I have dropdown to change culture. saving the value in cookies..
if someone will direct write www.abc.com/fr then it should change cookies value also.

How can I achieve with routes?

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" , culture=  UrlParameter.Optional}
                );
```

Comment: What is not working ? What is your expected behavior ? Do you have a predefined set of cultures strings or it can be any 2char strings ? You want to set it only for the `home/index` action ?

Comment: @Shyju 
Suppose by default it will be English culture & it will be end of the web url. 
In case of fr culture then all the page url will be 
abc.com/fr , 
abc.com/fr/myfirstpage, 
abc.com/fr/secondpage.. 

I have one language dropdown if someone will change from french to English then no need to append language code,  and all url will be without /fr... like below
abc.com/ ( Home page ) , 
abc.com/myfirstpage, 
abc.com/secondpage.. 
When I change culture I am setting cookies value and set 
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture with changed culture value..
I hope its clear now?

Comment: @Shyju yes I am using 2 character string of culture..
I have predefined culture..
English & French now,
Maybe in future add more 1 as per the requirement..
we are getting client's browser culture and set resources from Resx files in MVC application..
I want to set culture to each controller & actions..
Is it possible to do with minimum code changes in MVC application?